# ATtiny861 SPI via USI Port A or Port B?

Tags: spi, datasheet, attiny

I'm struggling to understand the [ATtiny861 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2588-8-bit-AVR-Microcontrollers-tinyAVR-ATtiny261-ATtiny461-ATtiny861_Datasheet.pdf) with respect to the pins available for SPI communication. My goal is to configure my ATtiny861 as a SPI peripheral and use my USBtinyISP programmer as the SPI controller. I will then use the avrdude commands to read the values output by the ATtiny861 via SPI.

Since my programmer is already wired up to the port B pins (PB0/MOSI, PB1/MISO, PB2/USCK) I'd like to use them with the USI module. However under figure 13-3 in the USI documentation it says:

> The output is set up by writing the data to be transmitted to the USI Data Register. The output is enabled by setting the corresponding bit in the Data Direction Register of Port A.

Does this mean that the USI module can only be used via the port A pins (PA0/DI, PA1/DO, PA2/USCK)? If so is there a way to use the port B pins as a SPI peripheral short of programming my own PCINT-based bit-level logic?

[image: pin diagram]
[image: three wire description]

Comment: (Consider [answering your own question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section under figure 13-3 is apparently an oversight or typo because section 13.5.5 documents a USIPP register that allows the selection of port A vs port B for the USI module. With this knowledge I was able to use the port B pins with the USI module.

[image: USIPP reference doc]